# It is possible to fetch data from the repository using typeorm for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, repository, typeorm

I'm making an api in which I separate my requests by responsibilities, services, repository and routes, I'm using typeorm to connect to the database, and I'm trying to implement unit tests to test my application so I have to unclip my code from the typeorm of so that my tests are not depending on it. However, at the time of decoupling, the typeorm is no longer able to connect with the bank, which is mongodb, returns the following error: ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "mongo" was not found.

I've been reading about it and from what I understood the typeorm wouldn't give full support to the mongo, that's why it failed. I would like to confirm with you if that would be the case and what would be the best alternative to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is supported by TypeORM (although I have not used it personally myself).

You can follow a short tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typeorm/typeorm_working_with_mongodb.htm).

What is not supported for Mongo is the typeorm "Migration" feature. For example see typeorm [issue 6695](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6695). Migration is an advanced topic and you probably do not need it. But if you do, a workaround is on stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63975424/158675).

But this Migration issue has nothing to do with your error. Almost certainly, your getConnection() call or ormconfig.json are incorrect. Start a with simple project based on the TypeORM Mongo tutorial, nothing else, verify you can connect to MongoDB, and work up from there.

Comment: I was using the typeorm with mongodb calmly, I was able to make the whole crud, it started to give a problem when I put the connection from a constructor like the code below: " constructor() {
    this.ormRepository = getRepository(Letter);
  } "